# Node bcrypt using async

Tags: node.js, bcrypt, async.js

I'm new to NodeJs and I'm trying to encrypt a text using the bcrypt library,
To execute the code serially, I'm using async series function,
I have two functions to encrypt the text, I am inserting them into an Array and passing the array to the async.series function,
But only the first method is getting executed.

**Following is my code -**

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var async = require('async');

const saltRounds = 10;
const myPlaintextPassword = 's0/\/\P4$$w0rD';

var hash1, hash2;
var seriesArray = [];

var one = function(callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function(err, hash) {
            console.log("Hash 1 => " + hash + "\n");
            hash1 = hash;

            bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash1, function(err, res) {
                console.log("Original Test of Hash1 => " + res + "\n");
            });
        });
    });
}

var two = function(callback){
    bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
        console.log("Hash 2 => " + hash + "\n");
        hash2 = hash;

        bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash2, function(err, res) {
            console.log("Original Test of Hash2 => " + res + "\n");
        });
    })
}
seriesArray.push(one);
seriesArray.push(two);

async.series(seriesArray,
function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the function execution you are not giving callback, so only one function is execution. You should give callback.

```
var one = function(callback){
bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function(err, hash) {
        console.log("Hash 1 => " + hash + "\n");
        hash1 = hash;

        bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash1, function(err, res) {
            console.log("Original Test of Hash1 => " + res + "\n");
            callback(err,res);

        });
    });
});
```

}

And for second function, code should be

```
var two = function(callback){
bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
    console.log("Hash 2 => " + hash + "\n");
    hash2 = hash;

    bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash2, function(err, res) {
        console.log("Original Test of Hash2 => " + res + "\n");
    callback(err,res)
    });
})
```

}

I hope it will work for you.